# How to allow workstations to use static routes from windows server

Tags: subnet, static-ip, mpls, routes

I have an MPLS network with 5 connected offices. 
All of the workstations can login to the domain controller at the main office. The DC at the main office can see all of the workstations at all of the offices. The DC has a static routing table for access to all of the office subnets. 
None of the computer workstations can see any of the other subnets. 
All of the workstations have static IP configurations. 
How do I get all of the workstations to be able to see all of the other stations on the different subnets? 
Can the workstations read the servers routing table, or do I need to add routes to all of the workstations?
Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?
Thanks in advance.